# How to produce three new columns from one column that has unequal length in Python (pandas or Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, split

I have a column that is a list of names, some have titles and some don't, how do I create the right columns for the right length for each row?

```
Names

Simon Cool
Mrs. Sarah Smart
Mr Harry Adams
Rupert Clever
Miss Jane Super
```

But I would like to have

```
Title    First Name     Last Name
         Simon          Cool
Mrs.     Sarah          Smart
Mr       Harry          Adams
         Rupert         Clever
Miss     Jane           Super
```

My code that does not work is:

```
import pandas as pd
title = []
firstname = []
lastname = []

saluations = ['Mr', 'Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Mrs.', 'Miss', 'Ms', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 'Lord', 'Lady']


x = df.names.str.split(' ').str[0]
y = df.names.str.split(' ').str[1]
z = df.names.str.split(' ').str[-1]

if x in saluations:
    title.append(x)
    firstname.append(y)
else:
    firstname.append(x)
lastname.append(z)
```

I have also tried:

```
import pandas as pd
for a in df.names.str.split(' ').str[0]:
    for b in df.names.str.split(' ').str[1]:
        if a in saluations:
            title.append(a)
            firstname.append(b)
        else:
            firstname.append(a)
        
for c in df.names.str.split(' ').str[-1]:
    lastname.append(c)
```

Any help you have for me I would be very grateful and also any pointers that would make my code neater.

Comment: Rather than `x in saluations`, prefer `saluations.startswith(x)`, to avoid spurious matches in middle of string. Also, consider appending a SPACE to `x`, so we won't misparse e.g. `'Lordina Mahama'` or `'Ladya Cheryl'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Split names in Title, First name, Last name

Assumptions:

1. Names consist of exactly two parts - first and last name in this order.
2. Names may be preceded by a respectful title.
3. At least one name is preceded by a title.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Prepare data

data = '''
Names
Simon Cool
Mrs. Sarah Smart
Mr Harry Adams
Rupert Clever
Miss Jane Super
Lordina Mahama
Ladya Cheryl
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# Process names

salutations = [
    'Mr', 'Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Mrs.', 
    'Miss', 'Ms', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 
    'Lord', 'Lady',
    'Sir', 'Master', 'Dr.',
]

names = (
    df['Names']
    .str.split(n=2)
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .set_axis(['Title','First Name','Last Name'], axis='columns')
)

not_title = ~names['Title'].isin(salutations)
names[not_title] = names[not_title].shift(1, axis=1)

names.fillna('', inplace=True)
display(names)
```

### Split names in title and arbitrary number of parts

Assumptions:

1. Names consist of at least the last name in the last position.
2. First Name comes first if exists.
3. Names may be preceded by a title.
4. There may not be a name with a title.

```
import pandas as pd

# Data preparation

data = {'Names': [
    'Simon Cool',
    'Mrs. Sarah Smart',
    'Mr Harry Adams',
    'Miss Jane Super',
    'Lordina Mahama',
    'Ladya Cheryl',
    'Dr. Jonson',
    'Sir Elton Hercules John',
    'Jon Bon Jovi',
    'Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle',
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# The main code

names = df['Names']

NumberOfParts = 4   # 2: First & Last names; 3: First, Middle, Last names; 4:...
NameID = {1:'First name', 2:'Middle name', 3:'Third name', 'last':'Surname'}
assert len(NameID) >= NumberOfParts    # make sure we have enough name IDs

salutations = [
    'Mr', 'Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Mrs.', 'Miss', 
    'Ms', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 'Lord', 'Lady', 
    'Sir', 'Master', 'Dr.',
]

parts = names.str.split(n=1)
has_salut = parts.str.get(0).isin(salutations)

title = parts[has_salut].str.get(0).rename('Title')
names[has_salut] = parts.str.get(1)   # clear titles from names
parts = [title]    # save title as the very first part of names

# if we are happy to lose any names out of NumberOfParts
# then put n=-1 in the line below; in this case
# we end up with first (NumberOfParts-1) parts of name and the last one,
# which is surname by default:
names = names.str.split(n=NumberOfParts-1)    # split names into Number of Parts

name_len = names.str.len()   # count obtained number of parts for each name

for i in range(1, NumberOfParts):
    parts.append(
        names[name_len > i].str.get(i-1).rename(NameID[i])
    )
    
parts.append(
    names.str.get(-1).rename(NameID['last'])
)

names = pd.concat(parts, axis=1).fillna('')

display(names)
```

Output on test data with `NumberOfParts = 4`:

[image: names]

Comment: Hi, @relent95, thank you for taking the time to answer this questions, but unfortunately I got an error message when I did it:  ValueError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns

Comment: Hi @ Vitalizzare, thank you for taking the time to answer this question, but unfortunately the first code you provided, I couldn't provide into pd.read_csv(StringIO(data) as the data has many columns in there and not just the names columns.

The second code did work however it didn't give me anything in Title column, all Titles were empty, only First Name, Middle Name and Last Name was populated.
Do you know how I can get the Titles populated? I think this code would work better for me.

Comment: @S.Toor I can't say why you obtained no titles, 'cause I've no idea how you implemented the code on your side. But to avoid misunderstanding, I've made some changes in both parts - separated **preparation** and **processing** data. The ides of the first part is _shift data without titles to the left_. The second part is just _splitting the names in parts_ assuming there's at least a surname at the very last position and then _concatenating them_.

Comment: To match your case put `NumberOfParts = 2`

Comment: thank you, yes you are right. I had extracted the titles first which I forgot about, sorry! This was because there were a few people in my data that had four names (so two middle names) e.g Mrs. Charlotte Susan Helen Smith, I extracted the title to see if the other names populated and they did.

So my question would be, if I can use the same method as you did, but for the last name, I want to just extract the last part of the string, which will always be the last name.

Can this be done in this code?

Comment: @S.Toor Put `NumberOfParts = 1` in the second code, run it. You'll see only titles and surnames. If you wanna extract from long names only title, first and last names (and drop everything that's in the middle), then try to remove parameter from `names = names.str.split(n=NumberOfParts-1)` - instead of it use `names = names.str.split()` - and use `NumberOfParts=2`

Comment: @S.Toor I added description to the code what to change in order to drop middle names

Comment: thank you, the last part of the code worked :)
I had thought it was much simpler but it wasn't, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the data row by row. You don't need to search fancy pandas APIs.

This is an example pseudo code.

```
import pandas

df = ...
honorifics = ['Mr', ...]

new_data = []
for name in df.names:
    tokens = name.split()
    if not tokens[0] in honorifics:
        tokens.insert(0, '')
    new_data.append(tokens)
new_frame = pandas.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['honorific', 'first', 'last'])
```